# OpenNLp training data for organisation

Tags: opennlp

I am trainng my data for opennlp organisation entity finder from command line but it's showing a null pointer exception

I have used:

> opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -model en-ner-person.bin -lang en -data >en-ner->person.train -encoding UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you use training data for "Person" type.

So firstly, you should create training data for type "Organization":

```
$ bin/opennlp TokenNameFinderConverter conll03 -data eng.train -lang en -types org > corpus_train_org.txt
```

Then train your model:

```
$ bin/opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -lang en -encoding utf8 -iterations 500 -data corpus_train_org.txt -model en_ner_organization.bin
```

Comment: what is this file eng.train?